# Down converting square wave

Tags: oscillator, wave, mixer

I'm making some experiences with relaxation oscillators using 74 series. I'm trying to down convert to square wave but I get confused.

Let's say I have 50khz square wave frquency generated with a relaxation oscillator.

And I have another oscillator which varies between 55-65 khz which is also a square wave.

I want to subtract constant 50khz frequency from varying frequency range and get a frequency which varies between 5-15khz range.

In rf oscillators this can be made with rf mixers. But I have a relaxation oscillator and 0-5v square wave. How would I achieve this process with logic gates or any other methods?

Comment: It depends. What does "down convert" mean to you? Do you want to divide the frequency by a constant factor, or do you want to subtract a constant value from it?

Comment: Actually subtract a constant value.

Comment: Preliminary answer, pending getting this question reopened: The logic equivalent of an analog mixer is the XOR (exclusive-or) gate. However, just like with an analog mixer, its output signal includes both the sum and difference frequencies. The easiest way to separate them is to feed the signal through an analog low-pass filter, and then use a comparator to "square up" the result.

Comment: Well I have seen before the theory of XOR gate but when I simulate I did not get the result that I'm expecting. Now that is clear it includes both sum and difference frequency. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One question you'll have to consider is how much jitter you can accept in your output.  If you know which input will be faster and you want an output which is synchronized to that, here's a version which might be useful.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flE4VR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1a and R1b act as a 2-bit gray-code counter on the slower signal.  The outputs from that are synchronized to the faster clock via R2a/R2b and xor'ed with a signal that toggles with that faster clock (since the graycode counter vales are "expected" to toggle each clock); they then go through a second synchronization in R3a/R3b.  The output from these would yield gray-code count value at the difference frequency, but it might have +/- one count of jitter.  The final flip flops "debounce" that gray-code count value, and the final XOR effectively yields the LSB of the count.  The output count will have approximately the same duty cycle as the lower-frequency signal.

Note that this circuit is much simpler than some other approaches such as using a simple XOR gate, or simply latching the state of one input each time the reference clock changes, but unlike those other approaches the output from this circuit will be clean even in the presence of phase jitter or other latching uncertainty (I don't know how to add such uncertainty to this simulator).  In the presence of jitter, the gray-code output of R3a/R3b may have +/- one count of jitter, but the flip flops add +/- one count worth of hysteresis to cancel it out.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. Well If I know the "jitter" concept right, that is something I always came across. Let's say I have a basic schmitt trigger oscillator and it normally shoud have run at 11.400000 Mhz (worst setup at breadboard). But when I look with an oscilloscope it always change around in example 11.402000 and 11.398000 Mhz. So assuming this circuit this jitter will be very low at the output right?

Comment: @cheour: As drawn, the jitter will be about +/- 1 cycle of the reference wave [since the output can only change on rising edges of that clock].  Using double-edge-triggered flops for the things controlled by CLK2 might reduce the jitter, but would make parts of the circuit a bit trickier.  BTW, I don't know the exact limitations, but I think the circuit will work for some input frequencies above the reference frequency as well as below; behavior right around the reference frequency (such that the signal goes both above and below) may be dubious, though.